# How to fix the Sqlite3 differing versions using Python?

Tags: sqlite

I had sqlite version `3.7.17` on centOS.
I then installed from source code `3.28.0`.

Unfortunately the `sqlite3` python module is still using version `3.7.17`.

Do I have to recompile python?

```
[root@jenkins ~]# python3.6
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 21 2019, 09:50:01) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.7.17'
>>> exit()
[root@jenkins ~]# sqlite3
SQLite version 3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .exit
```

Comment: What problem are you solving with sqlite newer than 3.7 ?

Comment: `Django 2.2.x supports SQLite 3.8.3 and later.`